# Реализация Dictionary на основе списка или вектора

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

**Задание**: реализовать свой обобщенный Dictionary на основе списка или массива.

**Вопрос:** список или массив лучше выбрать за основу? На сколько знаю, если брать список то поиск будет O(n), если отсортированный - O(log n), но в Dictionary должен же быть O(1). Знаю что в .net Dictionary написан на хеш-таблице, возможно ли написать хеш-таблицу на основе массива или списка?
Подскажите какой выбор будет оптимальней?

Comment: что такое "вектор"?

Comment: Сделать и то и другое, сравнить эффективность.

Comment: Dictionary в  дотнете по своей сути и есть хеш таблица. Список или массив в ней будет использоваться не особо принципиально, доступ по индексу и там и там одинаковый. Требование "оптимальней" непонятно, оптимальней для чего? Вставки? Поиска? Сортировки? Оптимальней по скорости? По памяти? Попробуйте формализовать ваш вопрос с подробностями и примерами.

Comment: `но в Dictionary должен же быть O(1)` доступ по ключу в словаре "псевдоконстантый", и очень сильно зависит от 1) Размера словаря 2) качества хеш функции. Если предположить, что коллизии исключены и количество элементов для хранения меньше размера словаря, то даже самая простейшая имплементация даст константный доступ.

Comment: `Подскажите какой выбор будет оптимальней?` тут тоже надо пояснить, оптимальней в асимптотике или на практике? Асимптотика что у списка, что у словаря, одинаковая. Спосок потому и называют "динамический массив", потому что операции в асимптотике занимают то ж самое время для обоих

Comment: а так, вот [имплементация дотнетная](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs,d3599058f8d79be0), там кода всего то 1к строк.

Comment: См. [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array): associative array, map, symbol table, or dictionary is an abstract data type. Он не накладывает требований к сложности. Главное, должны быть реализованы операции вставки, поиска, удаления.

Comment: У хеш-таблицы поиск действительно O(1). Но словарь/мапа/ассоциативный массив не обязаны быть основаны на ней. / В C++ std::map реализована на красно-чёрном дереве со сложностью O(log n).

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov автору надо быть более конкретным, потому как у Dictionary есть вполне определенные требования к скорости. А вот у IDictionary уже требований к скорости нет.

Comment: Вопрос решён? Напишите ответ, как именно сделали. / Если вы просто скопировали дотнетную имплементацию, то вы провалили задание.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В итоге сделала на двухсвязном списке.
Вот если кому-то интересно. Буду рада любым комментариям.

```
public class Dictionary<TKey, TValue> : IDictionary<TKey, TValue>
    {
        private readonly DoublyLinkedList<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> _items;

        public TValue this[TKey key] 
        { 
            get => _items.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Key.Equals(key)).Value;
            set => Add(key, value);
        }

        public ICollection<TKey> Keys => (ICollection<TKey>)_items.Select(item => item.Key);

        public ICollection<TValue> Values => (ICollection<TValue>)_items.Select(item => item.Value);

        public int Count => _items.Count;

        public bool IsReadOnly => false;

        public Dictionary()
        {
            _items = new DoublyLinkedList<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>();
        }

        public void Add(TKey key, TValue value)
        {
            if (key == null)
                throw new ArgumentException(nameof(key));
            if (value == null)
                throw new ArgumentException(nameof(value));
            Add(new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>(key, value));
        }

        public void Add(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
        {
            if (ContainsKey(item.Key))
                throw new ArgumentException($"The dictionary already contains a value with key {item.Key}", nameof(item));
            _items.Add(item);
        }

        public void Clear()
        {
            _items.Clear();
        }

        public bool Contains(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
        {
            return _items.Contains(item);
        }

        public bool ContainsKey(TKey key)
        {
            if (key == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(key));
            return _items.Any(item => item.Key.Equals(key));
        }

        public void CopyTo(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>[] array, int index)
        {
            _items.CopyTo(array, index);
        }

        public bool Remove(TKey key)
        {
            if (key == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(key));
            return Remove(_items.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Key.Equals(key)));
        }

        public bool Remove(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
        {
            if(!ContainsKey(item.Key))
                return false;
            return _items.Remove(item);
        }

        public bool TryGetValue(TKey key, [MaybeNullWhen(false)] out TValue value)
        {
            if (!ContainsKey(key))
            {
                value = default(TValue);
                return false;
            }
            value = this[key];
            return true;
        }

        public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> GetEnumerator()
        {
            foreach (var item in _items)
            {
                yield return item;
            }
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return ((IEnumerable)this).GetEnumerator();
        }
```

Comment: А зря. Вы же преимуществами двусвязного списка не пользуетесь, только теряете производительность из-за нелокальности обращений к памяти.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, что вы имеете ввиду и как можно это улучшить?

Comment: Если вы не храните ссылки на ноды для быстрого удаления и не удаляете элементы из начала - лучше использовать List.

Comment: Поняла, спасибо.