# В чём отличие hashtable и dictionary в C#?

Tags: c#, структуры-данных, data-structures

Всем добрый день, не совсем понятно отличие между ассоциативным массивом, хэш-таблицей(hashtable) и словарём(dictionary/map) и как это проявляется в языке c#.
Как я понял, есть ADT - хэш-таблица которая представлена хэш-функцией и массивом - кормим ей ключ и значение => хэш-функция(над ключом) => индекс в массиве => операция над входными данными. Могут возникнуть коллизии которые решаются либо открытой адресацией(пробирование) либо связанным списком и вот тут встал вопрос - а чем это отличается от словаря и ассоциативного массива и как это проявляется в C#(отличие hashtable и dictonary?) Где-то говорят что словарь это та же хэш-функция в которой коллизии решаются через открытую адресацию, где-то что это(словарь) абстрактное нечто что должно уметь работать с парой ключ/значение и это может быть реализовано хоть через дерево. Во-общем, помогите пожалуйста разобраться.
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: [Ассоциативный массив](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ассоциативный_массив) ([eng](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array)) - это _абстрактный_ тип данных. Map, Dictionary - это просто другие его названия. / Конкретная реализация может быть сделана в виде хеш-таблицы, красно-чёрного дерева и много чего ещё. Вот [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1452754/184217) на двусвязном списке.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! А в чём отличие их отличие в контексте C#(классы hashtable и dictionary)?

Comment: Один не обобщенный (хештейбл), второй обобщенный (дикшонари)

Comment: Тут основные отличия описаны: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301371/why-is-dictionary-preferred-over-hashtable-in-c